# What distribution has this pdf and CDF?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, density-function, cumulative-distribution-functions

I am using the following probability distribution function defined for $x \in [0, \infty)$ with $\alpha>0$:

$$ f(x\mid\alpha)= \frac{\alpha}{(x+\alpha)^2}$$
the CDF is
$$ F(x\mid\alpha)= \frac{x}{x+\alpha}$$

does this distribution have a name? Has it been studied?

Comment: This probability distribution is known as the log-logistic distribution with shape parameter $\beta = 1$.

Comment: Thanks for your clear answer!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this distribution has a name, but it is closely related to a well-studied distribution. If $X$ is Pareto-distributed with scale $\alpha$ and shape $1$ (this is a bit confusing since $\alpha$ normally denotes the shape), then the random variable $X-\alpha$ has density $f(\cdot\mid\alpha)$ and CDF $F(\cdot\mid\alpha)$.